# Meteor - Trying to return a built URL in a helper, coming back blank?

Tags: meteor, href, helper, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to return a URL that I build up in a helper and add it to my href, but its coming back blank.  I'm console.logging my final URL and its correct. I"ve tried single quotes, double and tripple {{{myhelper}}}.  But it returns blank and removes the HREF attribute altogether???

my .html  within a loop, passes the row.

```
<td class="table__cell">
    <a href={{ buildUCDLink row }} >go</a>
</td>
```

my .js helper

```
buildUCDLink(process){
  const thisTemplate = Template.instance();
  const integrations = thisTemplate.integrations.get();
  integrations.forEach((integration) => {
   if (integration._id._str === process.integration_id._str ) {
     const finalUcdUrl = integration.ucd_url + '/#applicationProcessRequest/' + process.id;
     console.log('finalUcdUrl: ', finalUcdUrl);
    return finalUcdUrl;
  }
});
```

},

Comment: Is your <td> within an `#each`? Where you getting `row` from? Perhaps more snippets will help.

Comment: @MoA yes its in a loop, the console.log is showing up as I want in the browser, but the return is not working for some reason.  Its almost like its blocking it because its a URL?  example from my console.log:  http://xx.xx.xx:8555/#applicationProcessRequest/51cdd49c-5906-44c5-aa86-da5a2559bccf

Comment: Try `<a href="{{ buildUCDLink row }}">go</a>`. If doesn't work, try to remove `row` from template, `process` from helper, and simply return a static value such as 'www.google.com', does it work then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for some reason I needed to reassign the var outside the loop.  This worked:

```
buildUCDLink(process){
const thisTemplate = Template.instance();
const integrations = thisTemplate.integrations.get();
let returnURL = '';
integrations.forEach((integration) => {
  if (integration._id._str === process.integration_id._str ) {
    const finalUcdUrl = integration.ucd_url + '/#applicationProcessRequest/' + process.id;
    returnURL = finalUcdUrl;
  }
});
return returnURL;
```

},

Answer (score 0):

That is not so easy to follow but if you are trying to trigger it from an anchor. I think you would want to run it like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="buildUCDLink(row);">
```

Which I think is long hand for:

```
<a href="javascript:buildUCDLink(row);">
```

If I am wrong, please let me know a bit more about what you are trying to do here.